# EF Core 3 - Using an extension method of string inside Where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a simple extension method for strings:

```
public static class FrenchStringExtensions
  {
    public static string ReplaceAccents(this string str)
    {
      return str
        .Replace("ç", "c")
        .Replace("é", "e")
        .Replace("ê", "e")
        .Replace("è", "e")
        .Replace("ë", "e")
        .Replace("â", "a")
        .Replace("à", "a")
        .Replace("î", "i")
        .Replace("ï", "i")
        .Replace("ô", "o")
        .Replace("û", "u")
        .Replace("ù", "u")
        .Replace("ü", "u");
    }
  }
```

When I try to call this method inside `Where()` clause like this:

```
var supportTeamsQuery = this.MasterContext.IncidentSupportTeams
        .AsNoTracking()
        .IsActive();

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern))
      {
        pattern = pattern.ToLower().ReplaceAccents().Trim();

        supportTeamsQuery = supportTeamsQuery
          .Where(st =>
            st.Name.ToLower().ReplaceAccents().Contains(pattern)
          );
      }
```

I have an error: *The LINQ expression could not be translated...*

If I use `Replace()` calls right inside `Where()` it works fine. For example:

```
supportTeamsQuery = supportTeamsQuery
          .Where(st =>
            st.Name
            .ToLower()
            .Replace("ç", "c")
            .Replace("é", "e")
            .Replace("ê", "e")
            ...
            .Contains(pattern)
          );
```

But I have several places in my code where I need to transform string this way so I want to move it to a separate method.

Is it possible to make it works?

Comment: IMO, instead of querying data this way (query will be ineffective), it's better to store normalized names. That is, you should call ReplaceAccents *before* storing name in database. Just store "name with accents" and "normalized name". The first one is for displaying data to user, the second one is for searching.

Comment: This error happens because your **LINQ** is going to be translated to **SqlServer Query** and it can't be (there is not built-in version of `ReplaceAccent` in SQL Server). If your data were in memory your function would works fine.

Comment: I think you can do vice versa, change you `pattern` string to accent type. This way your query would work.

Comment: What you are trying to do seems to be re-inventing collation accent sensitivity. Just change collation of your database to accent insensitive (AI) or if you need only on a certain query you need to use EF Core 5 see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity

Comment: You can also get rid of ToLower by using case insensitive (CI) collation instead of case sensitive (CS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference here that when you inline methods in `Where` clause, compiler generates Expression Tree with several Replace calls. When you call `ReplaceAccents`, compiler generates only this call and EF can not access to body of that method. So you need a way to expand Expression Tree.

There are many solutions to do that. But try this extension, which is designed for that.
https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq/

According to the documentation, you have to do the following code changes:

```cs
public static class FrenchStringExtensions
{
    [InjectLambda]
    public static string ReplaceAccents(this string str)
    {
       _replaceAccentsFunc ??= ReplaceAccents().Compile();
       return _replaceAccentsFunc(str);
    }

    Func<string, string> _replaceAccentsFunc;

    private static Expression<Func<string, string>> ReplaceAccents()
    {
       return str =>
         .Replace("ç", "c")
         .Replace("é", "e")
         .Replace("ê", "e")
         .Replace("è", "e")
         .Replace("ë", "e")
         .Replace("â", "a")
         .Replace("à", "a")
         .Replace("î", "i")
         .Replace("ï", "i")
         .Replace("ô", "o")
         .Replace("û", "u")
         .Replace("ù", "u")
         .Replace("ü", "u");
    }
}
```

Then you can use your function after `ToInjectable()` call

```cs
var supportTeamsQuery = this.MasterContext.IncidentSupportTeams
        .ToInjectable()
        .AsNoTracking()
        .IsActive();

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern))
      {
        pattern = pattern.ToLower().ReplaceAccents().Trim();

        supportTeamsQuery = supportTeamsQuery
          .Where(st =>
            st.Name.ToLower().ReplaceAccents().Contains(pattern)
          );
      }
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for!