# Converting entity models to models in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, model, linqkit

Say that I've got two database tables: Order and OrderLine.

According to [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257507/should-an-asp-net-mvc-application-directly-use-entity-framework-as-the-model) it is considered good practise to create copies of the database models and use them rather than the database models.

So you typically see converter methods like this.

```
public OrderModel ToOrderModel(Order order)
{
    return new OrderModel
    {
        OrderID = order.OrderID,
        Customer = order.CustomerName,
        OrderLines = order.OrderLines
    };
}

public OrderLineModel ToOrderLineModel(OrderLine orderLine)
{
    return new OrderLineModel
    {
        OrderLineID = orderLine.OrderLineID,
        Quantity = orderLine.Quantity,
        Product = orderLine.ProductName,
        Order = orderLine.Order
    };
}
```

The trouble with this, in my opinion, is:

- The `OrderLines` property in an `OrderModel` is a list of type `OrderLine` rather than `OrderLineModel`.
- The `Order` property in an `OrderLineModel` is of type `Order` rather than `OrderModel`.

I've found two solutions to this but both have their limitations and I'm hoping somebody will be able to suggest a better way.

#### Solution 1

This solution works but it only works in "LINQ to Objects" and not in "LINQ to Entities".
It's also a little bit over-complicated.

```
public OrderModel ToOrderModel(Order order)
{
    return ToOrderModel(order, null);
}

private OrderModel ToOrderModel(Order order, List<OrderLineModel> orderLines )
{
    //Creating model early so that we have a reference to pass later on
    var orderModel = new OrderModel();

    orderModel = new OrderModel()
    {
        OrderID = order.OrderID,
        Customer = order.CustomerName,
        OrderLines = orderLines ?? order.Lines.ToList().Select(x => ToOrderLineModel(x, orderModel)) 
    };
}

public OrderLineModel ToOrderLineModel(OrderLine orderLine)
{
    return ToOrderLineModel(orderLine, null);
}

private OrderLineModel ToOrderLineModel(OrderLine orderLine, OrderModel orderModel)
{
    //Creating model early so that we have a reference to pass later on    
    var orderLineModel = new OrderLineModel();

    return new OrderLineModel
    {
        OrderLineID = orderLine.OrderLineID,
        Quantity = orderLine.Quantity,
        Product = orderLine.ProductName,
        Order = orderModel ?? ToOrderModel(orderLine.OrderModel, orderLineModel),
    };
}
```

#### Solution 2

This solution makes use of [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) and works in "LINQ To Entities". The only problem is that I have to choose between either:

- The `OrderLines` property in an `OrderModel` being a list of `OrderLineModel`.
- The `Order` property in an `OrderLineModel` having the type of `OrderModel`.

```
 public static Expression<Func<Order, OrderModel>> ToOrderModel =
    order => new OrderModel()
    {
        OrderID = order.OrderID,
        Customer = order.CustomerName,
        Lines = order.OrderLines.Select(orderLine => ToJournalLineModel.Invoke(orderLine)),
    };

public static Expression<Func<OrderLine, OrderLineModel>> ToOrderLineModel =
    orderLine => new OrderLineModel()
    {
        OrderLineID = orderLine.OrderLineID,
        Quantity = orderLine.Quantity,
        Product = orderLine.ProductName,
        //Sadly we can't add an OrderModel here :(
    };

//example usage
var orderModels = dbContext.Orders.AsExpandable().Select(ToOrderModel);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: One word: AutoMapper.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64983665/ef-core-3-using-an-extension-method-of-string-inside-where-clause/64985701#64985701
It is the same that you want to achieve.