# Entity Framework Core combine expression in where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have wrap some logic into an expression because I use this piece of code multiple times (`FirstOrDefault` etc.)

```
public static class Expressions
{
    public static Expression<Func<Y, bool>> Intersection(DateTime from, DateTime until)
    {
        return x =>
                from >= x.from.Date && bis <= x.until.Date
                || from<= x.from.Date && bis >= x.from.Date 
                || from<= x.until.Date && bis >= x.until.Date;
    }
}
```

I am on a point where I have to use the same logic combined in a more complicated query:

```
var result = await (from x in DbContext.X
                    join y in DbContext.Y on x.Id equals y.Id
                    where x.Status != Status.Failed
                          && x.Id != "foobar"
                          && Expressions.Intersection(y.from, y.until)
                    select new {...}).ToListAsync();
```

which results in a compiler error:

> Error CS0019  Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'Expression<Func<Y, bool>>'

If I use

```
Expressions.Intersection(y.from, y.until).Compile().Invoke(Y)
```

it will run the code but expression is evaluated in memory and not translated  into a SQL statement what I would prefer.

Is there a way to reuse my expression in this case?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64983665/ef-core-3-using-an-extension-method-of-string-inside-where-clause/64985701#64985701

Comment: You could use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to expand the `Expression`, or if you switch to fluent syntax, just make a second call to `Where(Intersection(`